# Replace all &#60; with < with perl on cygwin

Tags: perl, escaping, command-prompt

I have Cygwin installed, I want to execute something like this on the command prompt:

```
perl -pne 's/&#60;/<' input > output
```

But I'm running into two separate issues with the `&` and `<` each needing to be escaped.

- something like `'s/&/&'` is an error at the perl level

  - "*Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1*"
- something like `'s/</<'` is an error at the shell level

  - "*The system cannot find the file specified.*"

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Actually I think the `&` problem also happened at the shell level, with `&` used to separate commands on a line. So it looks like I just need to figure out how to escape both `&` and `<` at the (DOS?) shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, if you have CygWin installed, you should be doing everything from `bash`, not `cmd.exe`. It has *much* more capability when it comes to processing and escaping command line arguments.

Having said that, you may try to use the `^` escape character. That's the standard one for `cmd.exe` and it may allow you to at least get rid of the problem with `<`:

```
Pax> echo <
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Pax> echo ^<
<
```

I haven't tried this since I don't have Perl installed on my local Windows VM. I *do* have CygWin on the laptop but, as I said, I tend to use `bash` there instead of `cmd.exe`. So all care and no responsibility on this answer :-)

```
Pax> echo s/&#60;/<
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Pax> echo s/^&#60;/^<
s/&#60;/</
```

Comment: Yep yep yep, this is getting me close. Will update with more details, just excited to report that it seems to work. And yes, I know I should just use bash. -- YEP! WORKIE! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the ending slash:

```
perl -pne 's/&#60;/</' input > output
```

<s>Since the & and the < are quoted between single quotes, they are not interpreted by the shell.</s>

Comment: Yep, this was also an issue. I needed to escape with `^` at `cmd.exe` as Pax said, and the pattern itself needs the ending slash as you said.